# how to check if value from external table is different than current table then update

Tags: sql-server

how to check if value from external table is different than current table then update.

I am updating student firstname from firstname of extstudent. if value is different then only update else dont update

```
Update student
SET FirstName = FirstName
FROM ExtStudent
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the two tables in your [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) statement so that you can compare the two.  Both tables have to have the same key so that you can match up the records in your table to your "external" table.  In my example below, I'm going to assume that the primary key of both tables is a field called `StudentId`.

```
Update Student
SET Student.FirstName = ExtStudent.FirstName
FROM Student
JOIN ExtStudent
ON Student.StudentID = ExtStudent.StudentID
Where Student.FirstName <> ExtStudent.FirstName
```

This will update the `Student` table and set the `FirstName` field to the matching record with the same `StudentID` in the `ExtStudent` table where the `FirstName` fields do not match.  Because this is an inner join, it will not update if no matching record is not found.

If you are updating multiple fields and want to update the record if any of the fields changed, then check for inequality for each field in the where clause separated by an `OR`.

You could technically leave off the where clause because if it doesn't change it would just be updating it to the same value.  However keep in mind that this does register as an update, so any update triggers would be fired for all the records... even the ones that didn't change.

Another issue you might run into is if your name fields are nullable.  The `where` clause will return false if either one of the fields are `null`, so it would not update.  You could account for this with the `isnull` function.

```
Where isnull(Student.FirstName,'') <> isnull(ExtStudent.FirstName,'')
```

If changed to a left join with this modification, it would update `FirstName` to `NULL` if no match was found.

Comment: what if there are multiple columns do we need to use AND or do we need to use OR in where clause

Comment: I added some more detail to my answer.